# MacBook Wifi dies, computer needs to be restarted

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I've been having a problem where my wifi dies frequently, and won't turn on again until the computer is restarted.  By "dies" I mean no wifi networks are visible - when you click the WIFI icon, it asks if you want to "Turn on Wifi" even though you never turned it off.  If you click "turn on wifi" nothing happens.  So I've been restarting the computer a lot. It's a 2013 Macbook Pro running OSX Yosemite, but the wifi problem existed before upgrading to Yosemite. I believe it's a hardware problem.

Has anyone else had this issue, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Did you forget to include some information? Either way, would you be able to help us with some more details? When did this start? Is it only one particular wifi, or any?

Comment: Updated question with details.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that avoids having to restart the computer:

Go to terminal and type

```
sudo ifconfig en0 down
```

And enter your password. This will cause the WIFI card to restart and (for me) the connection to be restored.

Comment: May be worth noting that `en0` not always is WiFi (depends on the Mac model).

Answer (score 0):

Get your Airport Card replace or you risk your data.

This problem is only going to get worse over time, later causing the Mac to lock up then to a point the Mac will hang during boot.

Every force shutdown you risk losing your files on the delicate HFS+ file system.